# Ecto query where string field contains other string

Tags: elixir, sql-like, ecto

I'm building a simple search feature and I want to find all the records that have a string within a string field.

Here's what I've attempted.

```
term = "Moby"
MyApp.Book
|> where([p], String.contains?(p, term))
|> order_by(desc: :inserted_at)
```

This would return the following books:

- Moby Dick
- Sandich Moby Lean
- My Mobyand Example

But I get:

```
`String.contains?(p, term)` is not a valid query expression
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to use `String.replace/3` to escape the `%` in the input (if it's entered by the end user) and then use `like` inside the query:

```
|> where([p], like(p.title, ^"%#{String.replace(term, "%", "\\%")}%"))
```

Example:

```
iex(1)> term = "Foo%Bar"
iex(2)> query = MyApp.Post |> where([p], like(p.title, ^"%#{String.replace(term, "%", "\\%")}%")) |> order_by(desc: :inserted_at)
#Ecto.Query<from p in MyApp.Post, where: like(p.title, ^"%Foo\\%Bar%"),
 order_by: [desc: p.inserted_at]>
iex(3)> Ecto.Adapters.SQL.to_sql(:all, MyApp.Repo, query)
{"SELECT p0.\"id\", p0.\"title\", p0.\"user_id\", p0.\"inserted_at\", p0.\"updated_at\" FROM \"posts\" AS p0 WHERE (p0.\"title\" LIKE $1) ORDER BY p0.\"inserted_at\" DESC",
 ["%Foo\\%Bar%"]}
```

If you do not do the replace, a term like `"a%b"` would match `"azb"` as the `%` needs to be escaped or it matches any sequence of zero or more characters.

Comment: Dogbert you rock. I wish I could follow users on StackOverflow. Treasure trove of Elixir goodies. :thumbsup:

Comment: You should also escape underscore, which matches any single character.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it:

```
results = 
  from b in Book,
  where: ilike(t.name, ^"%#{params["term"]}%"),
  order_by: [desc: :inserted_at]
```

Comment: You do that and say hello to SQL injection attacks. Do it the MattW's way.

Comment: @JustMichael he needs to add `%` on front and back of the user given term, how else would he do it?

Comment: @JustMichael There's no SQL injection here, but if `params["term"]` contains any `%`, they'll be treated as matching any sequence of zero or more characters. Also, MattW's current code will not work.